# user input can only be alphabetical characters and includes spaces

Tags: python, string

I am looking to ask the user to input their first and last name and validate it so that it is only alphabetical letters and spaces and then add it to a text file.

**This is the edited code from your suggestions and it always returns the first print message even though letters have been entered

```
while True:
    new_Book_AuthorFName = input('Enter Author First Name: ')
    new_Book_AuthorLName = input('Enter Author Last Name: ')  
    new_Book_Author_Name = new_Book_AuthorFName + " " + new_Book_AuthorLName
    try:
        new_Book_Author_Name.replace(' ', '').isalpha()
        print("Please Only Use Alphabetical Characters in Name.")
        continue
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid Name.")
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
def include_letter_and_spaces_only(string):
    return "".join(string.split(" ")).isalpha()
```

And then use as:

```
include_letter_and_spaces_only("test Test Test") # True
include_letter_and_spaces_only("test 12 Test Test") # False
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest and most pythonic way to be:

```
def is_alpha_and_spaces_only(string):
    return string.replace(' ', '').isalpha()
```

Faster and more efficient than [KetZoomer's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64921861/7212929) as it does not require you to **(a)** split string & **(b)** combine it back to have result.

P.S. Or just the spirit of the function if you dont want to define that. Just use `new_Book_Author_Name.replace(' ', '').isalpha()` inplace of if not `new_Book_Author_Name.isalpha()`

Comment: Define this function before your code & use this func where you want to check. i.e. use:`if not s_alpha_and_spaces_only(new_Book_Author_Name)` inplace of `if not new_Book_Author_Name.isalpha():`

Comment: Or just the spirit of the function if you dont want to define that. Just use `new_Book_Author_Name.replace(' ', '').isalpha()` inplace of `if not new_Book_Author_Name.isalpha()`

Answer (score 0):

I would do this as.

```
def lettersOnly(theString: str) -> bool:
    """Determine if a string only contains letters and spaces or not."""
    return ''.join(
        theString.split(' ')
    ).isalpha()
```